# Getting the value from a column or row after a query in Mysql or Mysql_async

Tags: rust, mysql-connector

The examples for all Rust mysql driver assume that data is ending up into a known struct.

The following we see a query mapping into a Payment struct:

```
struct Payment {
    customer_id: i32,
    amount: i32,
    account_name: Option<String>,
}

// Load payments from database. Type inference will work here.
let loaded_payments = conn.exec_map(
    "SELECT customer_id, amount, account_name FROM payment",
    (),
    |(customer_id, amount, account_name)| Payment { customer_id, amount, account_name },
).await?;
```

The table schema and the order is needed.
What if the unbelievable happens and a schema is unknown. Or we issued `SELECT * FROM payment` where the order is not followed.

Im using mysql_async although it seems that mysql is a very similar api.

I managed to get to this point noting the use `Row` since the the type is unknown.

```
let results:Result<Vec<Row>> = conn.query("SELECT * FROM person LIMIT 1");

for row in vec.iter() {
     println!("Row: {:?}", row); 
     // Prints the row and shows the columns with Bytes value 
     // such as Row { firstname: Bytes("qCEgkGSJ.."), lastname: Bytes("lYmsvbhT..") ... }

     let columns = row.columns();

     for index in 0..columns.len() { // The index is needed for row.get below
          let col = &columns[index];

          println!("Type: {:?}", col.column_type()); // MYSQL_TYPE_STRING works
          println!("Name: {:?}", col.name_str()); // "firstname" correct

          // Now the difficulty. Not sure if we get the value from row
          // we can use the same index 
          // And it panics
          // And we ask for String because of the MYSQL_TYPE_STRING
          let v:std::option::Option<String>  = row.get(index);
```

panicked at 'Could not retrieve alloc::string::String from Value'

Im unsure whether to get the value from row.get(index) and whether the index from column is valid for row.

Comment: Should be able to get it as an `Option<`[`Value`](https://docs.rs/mysql/latest/mysql/enum.Value.html)`>`

Comment: `Option<Value>` does get the value without a panic. But ... how to proceed to the underlying string, int or so forth.

Comment: jeepers. despite its name, the `to_sql()` method seems to return a string using a variety of [formats](https://docs.rs/mysql_common/0.27.5/src/mysql_common/value/mod.rs.html#244)

Comment: `Value` is an enum, so you can use pattern matching to get the appropriate types out of it.

Comment: yes, the `to_sql` method is doing just that. Are you familiar with identifying a binary column. A column of sql type `BINARY` is identified as a `MYSQL_TYPE_STRING` in the driver. Same as the C driver actually. But the c driver had a `is_binary` method permitting a field conversion.

Comment: for a binary column, the `col.flags` contains `BINARY_FLAG`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with NULL values from DB.
Here is a workaround that might be helpful for someone. Using take_opt you take control over panics.

```
let mut t:String = "".to_string();
let mut b:String = "".to_string();
if let Some(title) = title {
    match title {
        Ok(title) => t = title,
        Err(e) => {t = "".to_string()}
    }
}
let body = row.take_opt("description");
if let Some(body) = body {
    match body {
        Ok(body) => b = body,
        Err(e) => {b = "".to_string()}
    }
}
```